# how to solve erro Generic Object Injection Sink eslint(security/detect-object-injection)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, typescript-eslint

I would like to be able to solve this problem without having to disable estlint.
And I would like to understand the reason for the error

```
const getMappedCard = (cardName: CardName) => {
  const mappedCards = {
    Mastercard: <Mastercard />,
    Visa: <Visa />,
    Hiper: <Hiper />,
    Amex: <Amex />,
    Hipercard: <Hipercard />,
    Elo: <Elo />,
    Jcb: <Jcb />,
    Diners: <Diners />,
  };

  
  return mappedCards[cardName] ?? <div>erro</div>; //error is here
};
```

```
const getMappedCard = (cardName: CardName) => {
  const mappedCards = {
    Mastercard: <Mastercard />,
    Visa: <Visa />,
    Hiper: <Hiper />,
    Amex: <Amex />,
    Hipercard: <Hipercard />,
    Elo: <Elo />,
    Jcb: <Jcb />,
    Diners: <Diners />,
  };

  // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection
  return mappedCards[cardName] ?? <div>erro</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can write this :

```
type CardName = 'Mastercard' | 'Visa' | 'Hiper' | 'Amex' | 'Hipercard' | 'Elo' | 'Jcb' | 'Diners';
```

else say if mappedCards has all keys from CardName. I think you can live with the eslint-disable-next-line.

```
  return mappedCards[cardName as CardName] ?? <div>erro</div>;
```

Would fix it (which looks quite strange), but which could be understandable if eslint-security is applied after ts transformed to js.

Comment: solve it by doing it differently :

Answer (score 0):

solve it by doing it differently :

```
const getMappedCard = (cardName: CardName) => {
  switch (cardName) {
    case "Mastercard":
      return <Mastercard />;
    case "Visa":
      return <Visa />;
    case "Hiper":
      return <Hiper />;
    case "Elo":
      return <Elo />;
    case "Amex":
      return <Amex />;
    case "Jcb":
      return <Jcb />;
    case "Diners":
      return <Diners />;
    case "Hipercard":
      return <Hipercard />;
    default:
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Erro</h1>
        </div>
      );
  }
};
```